# Swift: Pass value between View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, detailview

***It's not a duplicate question!!***
I've searched for many similar questions, but I can't find someone declaring/calling the data model as a class like me.

I want to pass my `store`'s information from `Table View Controller` to `Detail View Controller`. I have trouble declaring the right type of variable `store` to receive the passed data in my `Detail View Controller`.

My Store Model:

```
class StoreModel{
    var name: String?
    var desc: String?
    var url: String?
    var rate: Double

    init(name: String?, desc: String?, url: String?, rate: Double){
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.url = url
        self.rate = rate
    }
}
```

In my `Table View Controller` I declared `store` to save the data from Firebase:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var storeList = [StoreModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //Hide some codes that initialize Firebase connection ...
        refStores.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0{
                for stores in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let storeObject = stores.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let storeName = storeObject?["storeName"]
                    let storeDesc = storeObject?["storeDesc"]
                    let storeUrl = storeObject?["storeUrl"]
                    let storeRate = storeObject?["storeRate"]

                    let store = StoreModel(name: storeName as! String?,
                        desc: storeDesc as! String?,url: storeUrl as! String?, 
                        rate: storeRate as! Double)
                    self.storeList.append(store)
                }
                self.tblSearch.reloadData()
    }})}
```

Below's my attempt:

In my Detail View Controller, I declare `storeList` to receive the passed data:

```
var storeList = [StoreModel]()
```

I create a segue (with identifier `showDetailView`) between my Table View Controller & Detail View Controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedStore = storeList[indexPath.row]
        let destinationVC = DetailViewController()
        destinationVC.storeList = selectedStore
        destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailView", sender: self)
}  }
```

I got the error message `Cannot assign value of type 'StoreModel' to type '[StoreModel]'`,    at the line 
`destinationVC.storeList = selectedStore`,    so I think I have problem declaring the right type of variable in my `Detail View Controller`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: At `Detail View Controller` Setup `var storeList = StoreModel()` not `Array`

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss Hi! This way shows error: `Missing argument for parameter 'name' in call`.

Comment: The most significant issue is `let destinationVC = DetailViewController()`. This is **not** the expected controller instance. The error is pretty clear: `selectedStore` is a **single** object and `storeList` expects **multiple** objects.

Comment: It certainly is a duplicate. Passing what the property at the far end expects is trivial and up to you. And now in comments your question has devolved into other stuff about Swift language basics, also trivial and also well covered here already.

Comment: @ayaio Hi, I can't find the "answer your question" button here, guess it's because my question's marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message describes *Cannot assign value of type 'StoreModel' to type '[StoreModel]'*. You are trying to assign a single instance of the model to an array in DetailViewController. Either declare

```
var storeList = StoreModel()
```

in DetailViewController. Or pass the value as

```
destinationVC.storeList = [selectedStore]
```

Also for creating an instance like

```
var storeList = StoreModel()
```

provide a no argument initializer.

```
class StoreModel() {
    var name: String?
    var desc: String?
    var url: String?
    var rate: Double

    init(name: String?, desc: String?, url: String?, rate: Double){
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.url = url
        self.rate = rate
    }
    init() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried both of your ways. Both popped up error : `Missing argument for parameter 'name' in call`

Comment: Please highlight the line number where the error is popped up

Comment: It's the line `var storeList = StoreModel()`

Comment: Since you have provided a parameterized initializer for the class you can not instantiate without calling the provided initializer. If you want to initialize like var storeList = StoreModel(). Add a no argument initializer to the class like init() {}.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure I understood your answer correctly. But I tried to add `init(){}` to my `StoreModel` class, it showed the error `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`.

Comment: Since rate is not optional you need to provide a default value to it in the initializer. Or mark rate as an optional. Also if rate is made optional you need to change argument type to optional in the parameterized initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only one Store data. So you need to change in Detail View Controller 
from this

```
var storeList = [StoreModel]()
```

to

```
var storeList:StoreModel!
```

And this is because here `let selectedStore = storeList[indexPath.row]` you are selecting just one selectedStore.

Comment: Hi! I've tried your method, the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<nightMarket.DetailViewController: 0x7fc18651c9e0>) has no segue with identifier 'showDetailView''` popped up. But I do set the identifier `showDetailView` to the segue.

Comment: @VanessaLeung Of course it crashes because it's not the controller in the storyboard. You have to override `prepare(for segue`. Study the duplicate.